# Add multi line string from variable into mysql with bash

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu, echo, tr

I'm running a python script which returns several lines of text, which I use the following truncate command `tr` and want to add to my database.

I start here: this removes the unformatted line delimiters.

`tr -d '\15\32' < long_text > unixfile.txt`

I'm then left with an output which looks like this:

```
Happy Birthday Stackoverflow

Happy Birthday to you

Happy Birthday Stackoverflow
```

I use the following command to place this into a variable:

```
lyrics=$(cat unixfile.txt)
```

```
mysql --user=USER --password=PASSWORD --database='DB' --execute='INSERT INTO `song_lyrics` (`id`, `song_id`, `lyrics`, `info`) VALUES ('"'$i'"', '"'$i'"', '"$lyrics"', '0');'
```

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1:
```

It seems that MySQL is seeing my entire 3 line string (shown above) in three different commands, because the output of the `unixfile.txt` appears in the error output.

Comment: Could it be that you missed a quote for SQL? Compare `'"'$i'"'` and `'"$lyrics"'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved using the following:

Ensure the long text string is being captured in a file, instead of a variable - then re-capture the file/variable.

```
lyrics=$(cat unixfile.txt)
```

```
mysql --user="$user" --password="$password" --database="$my_db" <<END
use my_db;
INSERT INTO song_lyrics (id, song_id, lyrics, info) VALUES ("$i", "$i", "$lyrics", '0');
END
```

this method ensures the variable is passed properly.

the only remaining issues would be with various types of punctuation
although this post does not describe this.